# Prolog File not being read despite file existing

Tags: prolog

Good day! I wrote a `load_rules` to be able to read files that I would be utilizing in my Prolog program. However, it seems that Prolog doesn't read my file, despite me having created it in the first place.

My code:

```
load_rules :-
  write('file name? '),
  read(F),
  load_rules(F).

load_rules(F) :-
 % clear_db,
  see(F),
  lod_ruls,
  write('rules loaded'), nl,
  seen, !.

lod_ruls :-repeat,
           read_word_list(L), size(L,X),write(X),nl,
           formal_english(L,[]), write('rule:    '), printlist(L), nl,
           translate(L,X),
           L=[end].
```

Query:

```
?- load_rules.
file name? joggers_facts_and_rules.

ERROR: source_sink `joggers_facts_and_rules' does not exist (No such file or directory)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] see(joggers_facts_and_rules)
ERROR:    [9] load_rules(joggers_facts_and_rules) at c:/users/user/desktop/formal_english.pl:88
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
?- :- debug.
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (:-)/1
ERROR:   Directives must be loaded from a file
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] throw(error(existence_error(procedure,...),_7042))
ERROR:    [8] '$dwim':dwim_existence_error(error,user:(:-)/1) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/dwim.pl:113
ERROR:    [6] '$dwim':correct_goal((:-debug),user,[],_7128) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/dwim.pl:85
```

I even tried creating a .txt as well as a .pl file just to be sure to no avail :/

I'd appreciate any help on this, many thanks!

Comment: This works for me if I create a file `joggers_facts_and_rules` without any file name extension. (Creating files without an extension is difficult on Windows, I think.) If there is an extension, you must quote the name and enter it as `'joggers_facts_and_rules.pl'`.

Comment: Check the documentation, but I would suspect that `load_rules` doesn't automatically assume and append the file extension. You need to give the full name.

Comment: Using `see/1` and `seen/0` is hopelessly outdated and [highly unreliable](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=edinburghIO).